# load xml to mysql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I am using "Load local xml" script to load xml file to mysql database with C#. 
The code is shown like this:

```
public void loadXML(string path, string table, string identify)
    {
        string query = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE ";
        query += "'"+path+"'";
        query += " INTO TABLE " + table;
        query += " Rows Identified By '<" + identify + ">';";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(query);
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }

    }
```

However I could not get this work. I am working with VS 2015.
It gives an mysqlException: 
    "Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset."
The InnerException is could not find the file, it's weird since that file is definitely not my target file.

Here shows the debug output:

```
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe</AppDomain>    <Exception><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ConsoleApplication1.DBConnect.loadXML() in C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\DBConnect.cs:line 124
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 47
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ---&amp;gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at ConsoleApplication1.DBConnect.loadXML() in C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\DBConnect.cs:line 124
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 47
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ---&amp;gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ---&amp;gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Lu\Google Drive\Capstone\CMPUT701\Project Codes\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\UsersLuDesktopperson.xml'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SendFileToServer(String filename)</ExceptionString></InnerException></InnerException></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the output of your Debug.Print? And please explain what does it mean _I could not get this work_. Do you have an exception? Simply the table is not updated? What else?

Comment: If you get an error, please show it..

Comment: I have post my debug print... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code you must

Cache the connection string but not the connection itself.

```
public void loadXML(string path, string table, string identify)
    {
    var con = new Connection(ConnectionString)
        string query = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE ";
        query += "'"+path+"'";
        query += " INTO TABLE " + table;
        query += " Rows Identified By '<" + identify + ">';";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(query);
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query,con );

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's not the problem, I open the connection in OpenConnection() function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure out. The problem is file path slash, I change \ into / then it works.